# Finding geodesics of hyperbolic plane.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation

I want to find the geodesics of  the hyperbolic plane, which has the metric $$ds^2=\frac{1}{y^2} (dx^2+dy^2)$$, as functions of $s$. 
I am given the result which is $$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=y^2$$ $$\dot{x}=ky^2$$.
Now I can understand how the first equation is derived but I have no idea how $\dot{x}=ky^2$ is derived. Can you explain how to derive it?

Also if I wanted to find the geodesics with respect to $t$, here is what I would do. 
$$s=\int \frac{1}{y} \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2} dt$$
And use the Lagrangian $$L=\frac{1}{y} \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+ \dot{y}^2}$$ to solve the Euler-Lagrange equations, but it seems that I would get some complicated differential equations like this. I want to ask if this approach is correct and if not what should I do instead?

Comment: The constant-speed parametrizations of the geodesics are quite awful. You can easily check that $\dot x=0$ gives solutions (so these are the vertical rays, without worrying about $y(t)$). Then, otherwise, you're much better off eliminating $t$ and doing Euler-Lagrange for $y=y(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

$ L(t, x,y, \frac {dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt}) =\frac{1}{y} \sqrt{(\frac {dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac {dy}{dt})^2} $

Noting that $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0 $ ,
use $ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{dx}{dt} } = 0  $ to get

$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{dx}{dt} } = $ constant

Now,

$ \frac {dx}{dt} = \dot x \dot s $ ,
$ \frac {dy}{dt} = \dot y \dot s $ ,

$ \frac {ds}{dt} = \dot s $ ,

$ \frac {dx}{ds} = \dot x $ ,
$ \frac {dy}{ds} = \dot y $ ,

$ {\frac{dx}{dt}}^2 +  {\frac{dy}{dt}}^2 = ({\dot x}^2 + {\dot y}^2){\dot s}^2 = y^2 {\dot s}^2 $

So,

$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{dx}{dt} } =  \frac {dx}{dt} /y({\frac{dx}{dt}}^2 +  {\frac{dy}{dt}}^2)^{\frac {1}{2}} = c $

Then,

$ \dot x = c y^2 $